# Weyl Tensor in Geometric Algebra

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, clifford-algebra

In [Gravity, Gauge theories and Geometric Algebra](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0405033), p.39, they derive the Weyl Tensor in the following manner:

> Six of the degrees of freedom in $\mathcal{R}(B)$ can be removed by
> arbitrary gauge rotations. It follows that $\mathcal{R}(B)$ can
> contain only 14 physical degrees of freedom. To see how these are
> encoded in $\mathcal{R}(B)$ we decompose it into Weyl and 'matter'
> terms. Since the contraction of $\mathcal{R}(a \wedge b)$ results in
> the Ricci tensor $\mathcal{R}(a)$, we expect that $\mathcal{R}(a \wedge b)$ will contain a term in $\mathcal{R}(a) \wedge b$. This must
> be matched with a term in $a \wedge \mathcal{R}(b)$, since it is only
> the sum of these that is a function of $a \wedge b$. Contracting this
> sum we obtain $$ \partial_a \cdot(\mathcal{R}(a) \wedge b+a \wedge
>  \mathcal{R}(b)) =b \mathcal{R}-\mathcal{R}(b)+4
>  \mathcal{R}(b)-\mathcal{R}(b) \\
>  =2 \mathcal{R}(b)+b \mathcal{R}, $$ and it follows that $$ \partial_a \cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{R}(a) \wedge b+a \wedge
>  \mathcal{R}(b))-\frac{1}{6} a \wedge b
>  \mathcal{R}\right)=\mathcal{R}(b) . $$ We can therefore write $$
>  \mathcal{R}(a \wedge b)=\mathcal{W}(a \wedge
>  b)+\frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{R}(a) \wedge b+a \wedge
>  \mathcal{R}(b))-\frac{1}{6} a \wedge b \mathcal{R}, $$
> Some questions arise for me:

- Why $R (a \wedge b)$ must contain a term $R(a) \wedge b$?
- Why only a sum of it plus $a \wedge R(b)$ is a function of $a \wedge
     b$?
- Can someone explain the steps in the first equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\MVects[1]{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge^{#1}}}
$The exterior power $\MVects 2V$ of a vector space $V$ is characterized by the following "universal property":

- Let $W$ be any other vector space. Every alternating multilinear map $g : V\times V \to W$ extends uniquely to a *linear* map $g' : \MVects 2V \to W$ such that $g'(a\wedge b) = g(a, b)$ for all $a, b \in V$.

What this means is that a linear function $f$ on $\MVects 2V$ is well-defined so long as $(a, b) \mapsto f(a\wedge b)$ is alternating on vectors $a, b$ (equivalently antisymmetric in the case of e.g. $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$).

The authors aren't so much saying that $\mathcal R(a\wedge b)$ *must* contain this turn, more so that it *ought to* and including it will show us what the traceless part of $\mathcal R(a\wedge b)$ is. For any linear function $f : V \to V$ the following identity is true:
$$
  \partial_a\cdot(f(a)\wedge b) = \partial_a\cdot f(a)\,b - b\cdot\partial_a\,f(a) = (\mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}f)b - f(b).
$$
In the particular case of $\mathcal R$
$$
  \partial_a\cdot(\mathcal R(a)\wedge b) = \partial_a\cdot\mathcal R(a)\,b - b\cdot\partial_a\,\mathcal R(a) = \mathcal Rb - \mathcal R(b)
$$
where $\mathcal R$ without an argument is the Ricci scalar. So we can get $\mathcal R(b)$ from this sort of term, and we know that $\mathcal R(b) = \partial_a\cdot\mathcal R(a\wedge b)$ so including this sort of term in $\mathcal R(a\wedge b)$ is natural. The universal property of $\MVects 2V$ tells us we can form a valid function of $a\wedge b$ by antisymmetrizing, so we want to focus on the form
$$
  \mathcal R(a)\wedge b - \mathcal R(b)\wedge a
$$
where $X$ is arbitrary. We can easily rewrite this as
$$
  \mathcal R(a)\wedge b + a\wedge\mathcal R(b).
$$
Applying $\partial_a\cdot$ in the same way as we did previously yields
$$
  \partial_a\cdot(\mathcal R(a)\wedge b + a\wedge\mathcal R(b)) = 2\mathcal R(b) + b\mathcal R.
$$
Now noting that similarly
$$
  \partial_a\cdot(a\wedge b) = 4b - b = 3b
$$
we see
$$
  \partial_a\cdot\left[\frac12(\mathcal R(a)\wedge b + a\wedge\mathcal R(b)) - \frac16\mathcal Ra\wedge b\right] = \mathcal R(b) = \partial_a\cdot\mathcal R(a\wedge b).
$$
Thus we put $\mathcal R(a\wedge b)$ in the form
$$
  \mathcal R(a\wedge b) = \mathcal W(a\wedge b) + \frac12(\mathcal R(a)\wedge b + a\wedge\mathcal R(b)) - \frac16\mathcal Ra\wedge b
$$
where $\mathcal W(a\wedge b)$ is an arbitrary function. This form is valid because the RHS is antisymmetric in $a, b$ and $\mathcal W$ is arbitrary and does whatever it needs to to make the equality happen. We now define the Weyl tensor as the necessary $\mathcal W$:
$$
  \mathcal W(a\wedge b) = \mathcal R(a\wedge b) - \frac12(\mathcal R(a)\wedge b + a\wedge\mathcal R(b)) + \frac16\mathcal Ra\wedge b.
$$
Note that by construction $\partial_a\cdot\mathcal W(a\wedge b) = 0$, i.e. $\mathcal W$ is traceless.