# Weyl Tensor and conformal transformations in Geometric Algebra

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, clifford-algebra

Geometric Algebra seems to provide numerous insights and simplify many calculations. However, I've seen very little about the [Weyl tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor).

I was wondering if anybody knows if it provides a more straightforward way to prove that:

1. The Weyl tensor is invariant under conformal transformations
2. The Weyl tensor vanishes for a [FLRW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) universe.

Maybe these identities have a geometric interpretation that gets better understood or simplified in GA.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730815/2451